# SQL authentication for different domain user

Tags: authentication, dns, sql-server-2012

This question is regarding SQL authentication for different domain user.

I have 2 servers on cloud. On server1 I have IIS and on Server2 I have SQL.

Both are on different domain, Server1 & Server2. 
I can access the SQL database using IP Address and vice versa.

I have a "Customuser" on "Server1", I want to connect to SQL using this user details.

From "Server2" I can't get "Server1" in Domain name or in user list. and vice versa.

I want to add "Server1\Customuser" on the "Server2" SQL.

Edit: I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: "SQL" is just the **structured query language** - a language designed to query databases. It doesn't have any "authentication" or other settings like that - a **database product** would have those - but you're not telling us **what concrete database** system you're using .... please add a relevant tag!

Comment: You can use SQL Authentication from any domain to any domain. the login must be created on the sql server itself, and you need to pass the user name and passowrd.

Comment: Problem is "How can I create a user of Server1 domain in SQL server which is in Server2?"   When I am creating the same, It throws the error.